# In Postgres 16 BETA, should the ParseNamespaceItem have the same index as it's RangeTableEntry?

Tags: c, postgresql, apache-age, postgresql-16

I have been working on updating Apache AGE with the latest version of Postgres, the `REL_16_BETA` version. One of the main problems that I am facing is the fact that the code was reworked to update the permission checking and now some of the queries return `ERROR:  invalid perminfoindex <rte->perminfoindex> in RTE with relid <rte->relid>`. This occurs due to one of the RTEs having `perminfoindex = 0` and the `relid` containing a value.

AGE allows us to execute openCypher commands within Postgres so that it can create a graph with nodes and edges. There are two main tables that are created: `_ag_label_vertex` and `_ag_label_edge`. Both of them will be the parent label tables of every other vertex/edge label we create.

When we do a simple `MATCH` query to find all nodes with the `v` label:

```sql
SELECT * FROM cypher('cypher_set', $$
MATCH (n:v)
RETURN n
$$) AS (node agtype);
```

inside the `add_rtes_to_flat_rtable()` function, it goes inside a loop where we can see the stored RTEs in `root->parse->rtable`:

```c
// I've simplified what every RTE shows.

root->parse->rtable
[
    (rtekind = RTE_SUBQUERY, relid =     0, perminfoindex = 0),
    (rtekind = RTE_SUBQUERY, relid =     0, perminfoindex = 0),
    (rtekind = RTE_SUBQUERY, relid =     0, perminfoindex = 0),
    (rtekind = RTE_RELATION, relid = 16991, perminfoindex = 1)
]
```

But executing the query with a simple `SET` clause:

```sql
SELECT * FROM cypher('cypher_set', $$
MATCH (n) 
SET n.i = 3
$$) AS (a agtype);
```

One of the RTEs of the `RTE_RELATION` type and `relid` with a not null value has `perminfoindex = 0`

```c
root->parse->rtable
[
    (rtekind = RTE_SUBQUERY, relid =     0, perminfoindex = 0),
    (rtekind = RTE_RELATION, relid = 16971, perminfoindex = 1),
    (rtekind = RTE_RELATION, relid = 16971, perminfoindex = 1),
    (rtekind = RTE_RELATION, relid = 16991, perminfoindex = 0)
]
```

We can see that the `relid = 16991` is related to the child vertex label and the `relid = 16971` related to the parent vertex label:

```sql
SELECT to_regclass('cypher_set._ag_label_vertex')::oid;
 to_regclass 
-------------
       16971

SELECT to_regclass('cypher_set.v')::oid;
 to_regclass 
-------------
       16991
```

With further inspection in AGE's code, after executing the `SET` query, it goes inside `transform_cypher_clause_as_subquery()` function and the `ParseNamespaceItem` has the following values:

```
{p_names = 0x1205638, p_rte = 0x11edb70, p_rtindex = 1, p_perminfo = 0x7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f, 
  p_nscolumns = 0x1205848, p_rel_visible = true, p_cols_visible = true, p_lateral_only = false, 
  p_lateral_ok = true}
```

And the `pnsi->p_rte` has:

```
{type = T_RangeTblEntry, rtekind = RTE_SUBQUERY, relid = 0, relkind = 0 '\000', rellockmode = 0, 
  tablesample = 0x0, perminfoindex = 0, subquery = 0x11ed710, security_barrier = false, 
  jointype = JOIN_INNER, joinmergedcols = 0, joinaliasvars = 0x0, joinleftcols = 0x0, joinrightcols = 0x0, 
  join_using_alias = 0x0, functions = 0x0, funcordinality = false, tablefunc = 0x0, values_lists = 0x0, 
  ctename = 0x0, ctelevelsup = 0, self_reference = false, coltypes = 0x0, coltypmods = 0x0, 
  colcollations = 0x0, enrname = 0x0, enrtuples = 0, alias = 0x12055f0, eref = 0x1205638, lateral = false, 
  inh = false, inFromCl = true, securityQuals = 0x0}
```

Then it calls `addNSItemToQuery(pstate, pnsi, true, false, true);`. This function adds the given nsitem/RTE as a top-level entry in the pstate's join list and/or namespace list.  I've been thinking if adding the nsitem/RTE like this won't cause this error?

Also in `handle_prev_clause` it has the following line, which is going to add all the rte's attributes to the current queries targetlist which, again, I'm not sure if that's what causing the problem because the relid of the rte is 0:

```c
query->targetList = expandNSItemAttrs(pstate, pnsi, 0, true, -1);
```

If someone knows more about it, I would be grateful for any kind of answer or help.

Comment: The answer will be found by asking the question here [pgsql-hackers](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/).

Comment: Hi @AdrianKlaver, this might sound as a silly question, but how should I send the question there? Do I need to write to someone in specific or does it have any page for writing a question or email there? Also, thanks for the quick comment :)

Comment: It's a mailing list [subscribe](https://lists.postgresql.org/) to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to thank Amit Langote and Tom Lane for helping me out on this one. I've sent some [emails](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CANQ0oxfxBKKTReQgSh_KbL99DqdjfBZTastC0XT2ZZMBkAhTQw%40mail.gmail.com) to pgsql-hackers regarding this issue and they have helped me on showing what could be the possible error.

When we do a `SET` query with AGE, the execution of the code goes through [`GetResultRTEPermissionInfo()`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/0a1d2a7df852f16c452eef8a83003943125162c7/src/backend/executor/execUtils.c#L1375) and it checks for `relinfo->ri_RootResultRelInfo`. This variable is pointing to nil. Because of this, Postgres will interpret that the `ResultRelInfo` must've been created only for filtering triggers and the relation is not being inserted into. Actually, we want to trigger the first if-statement

```c
    if (relinfo->ri_RootResultRelInfo)
    {
        /*
         * For inheritance child result relations (a partition routing target
         * of an INSERT or a child UPDATE target), this returns the root
         * parent's RTE to fetch the RTEPermissionInfo because that's the only
         * one that has one assigned.
         */
        rti = relinfo->ri_RootResultRelInfo->ri_RangeTableIndex;
    }
```

Because of that, it ends up having the wrong index and pointing to the wrong RTE, triggering the error in `getRTEPermissionInfo()`.